# Nuget: What is the purpose of the <package requireReinstallation /> attribute in packages.config?

Tags: c#, nuget

I upgraded my C# project (which already had some nuget packages) from 4.0 to 4.5.2. I saw that some `<package />` elements now contain an additional attribute `requireReinstallation="true"`.

- What is the purpose of this?
- Why is that some packages have while others don't.

Before

```
<package id="NLog" version="3.1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

After

```
<package id="NLog" version="3.1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" requireReinstallation="true" />
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the [release notes](http://blog.nuget.org/20130814/nuget-2.7-release-candidate.html)

> If we detect that any of your packages were affected by the retargeting or upgrade, we’ll produce immediate build errors to let you know. In addition to the immediate build error, we also persist a requireReinstallation="true" flag in your packages.config file for all packages that were affected by the retargeting, and each subsequent build in Visual Studio will raise a build warnings for those packages.

Essentially, NuGeT is automatically flagging packages which conflict with your project target or version

Comment: The cleanest way I found to reinstall these packages without upgrading them was to use the Package Manager Console, `Update-Package` instructions can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#using-update-package

Comment: Yes, specifically the "-Reinstall" option of Update-Package to avoid upgrading versions.  Also, ensure to target only specific projects in the solution with the "-ProjectName" option and only update packages for projects *owned* by the current solution, because the DLL hint paths added to the project's references will be relative to the currently opened solution's package directory.  In other words, if a project is included in multiple solutions, make sure you only update/install packages for that project when a solution in the solution folder the project exists under is open.

Comment: TLDR : `Update-Package <package_name> -ProjectName <my_project> -reinstall`

Comment: (and for those who have a lot of projects in the solution they inherited): Update-Package <package_name> –reinstall -verbose (reinstall the package in all projects of the solution if needed)

Comment: @Triynko I ran -reinstall without specifying a project and it updated all projects, some of which didn’t have the attribute. Why is this potentially a problem?

Comment: I don't understand this voodoo crap. I'm just ignoring the extra attribute. :)

Comment: "Essentially, NuGeT is automatically flagging packages which conflict with your project target or version" - So then is this something bad that I need to look into? My project compiles/runs fine.